# How to import OrmLite in Android project using Bazel?

Tags: android, bazel, ormlite

I am trying to import Ormlite in my Android project which is using Bazel build system.

This is what I did in WORKSPACE file,

```
maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.17",
        # ...
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1",
        # ...
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ],
```

And I am importing these dependencies in BUILD file as,

```
"@maven//:com_j256_ormlite_ormlite_core",
"@maven//:com_j256_ormlite_ormlite_android",
```

I am getting this error,

```
no such package '@maven//': Unable to run coursier: /my/home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_sensen/48
    ...ad891aa751c50/external/maven/coursier: line 2: exec: java: not found
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAQJR.png)

Comment: Yeah `exec: java: not found` is the key part of that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `java` installed on your system to run `coursier` to fetch the dependencies. [Follow these steps](https://openjdk.java.net/install/) to download OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks @jin. Its working as expected after installing java.